# How to use list inside success function of ajax returned by struts

Tags: ajax, struts2

I have made an ajax call which is mapped to the action class of struts. This action class returns a list. How should I retrieve this list and use it inside success function, i.e., how should i configure struts.xml file so that it returns list and then how to use it my js function?

Struts.xml file:

```
<action name="getInfo" class="package1.MyClass">
</action>
```

Action Class:

```
public String doExecute() throws Exception {
    try{
        this.list = loadInfo(id);

        return SUCCESS;
    }catch(Exception e) {

        //logger
    }
    return NONE;
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url,                      
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Show your code please, this will help us find the issue and not write the code from scratch for you.  thanks

Comment: Added need to use list inside success function

Comment: Where you want to use that List in your JSP ?

Comment: The html is already defined, based on the values returned I want to change the classes of the html elements. I know, we need to configure the action tag in struts.xml file. Just dont know how to do it. In other words, I simply want the List to iterate using for loop in my javascript function

Comment: Use `struts2-json-plugin`